# use saveGIF to create animation in R

Tags: r, windows, animation

I was trying to use the function saveGIF in package 'animation' . I have installed the required external software ImageMagick. The trial codes are as follows:

```
library(animation)

ani.options(convert = 'C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16\\convert.exe')
saveGIF({
  for (i in 1:10) plot(runif(10), ylim = 0:1)
})
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Executing: 
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0 -delay 100
    Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png
    Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "animation.gif""
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
an error occurred in the conversion... see Notes in ?im.convert
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0  -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "animation.gif""' had status 1 
2: In cmd.fun(convert) :
  '"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0  -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "animation.gif""' execution failed with error code 1
3: running command '"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0  -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "animation.gif""' had status 127
```

Noted from the **Notes** in ?im.convert

> **ImageMagick users** Please install ImageMagick from http://www.imagemagick.org, and make sure the the path to convert.exe
>   is in your 'PATH' variable, in which case the commandconvert can be
>   called without the full path. Windows users are often very confused
>   about the ImageMagick and 'PATH' setting, so I'll try to search for
>   ImageMagick in the Registry Hive by
>   readRegistry('SOFTWARE\ImageMagick\Current')$BinPath, thus you might
>   not really need to modify your 'PATH' variable. For Windows users who
>   have installed LyX, I will also try to find the convert utility in the
>   LyX installation directory, so they do not really have to install
>   ImageMagick if LyX exists in their system (of course, the LyX should
>   be installed with ImageMagick). Once the convert utility is found, the
>   animation option 'convert' will be set (ani.options(convert =
>   'path/to/convert.exe')); this can save time for searching for convert
>   in the operating system next time.

Is it wrong I can understand these as that if the path to convert.exe is not in my PATH variable, I need to specify the full dir to convert.exe?

Is there something wrong in the setting or calling convert.exe?

Comment: Your code works nicely on my R. Check carefully if the path `C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16\\convert.exe` is correct.

Comment: I'm on linux, so can't test this, but I think that in Windows you need to have quotes around path that contains spaces. Try `ani.options(convert = "'C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16\\convert.exe'")`

Comment: Marco Sandri, Yes, this path to convert.exe is indeed correct. This is also the default installation dir.

Comment: dww, No, that's not here. Tried but error

Answer (score -1):

```
saveGIF({

  for (i in dflaser10sec1$seg) {

    title <- as.character(i)

    g1 <- ggplot(dflaser10sec1, aes(x = dflaser10sec1$value, y = dflaser10sec1$pos, fill = dflaser10sec1$pos, width = 1)) +
      coord_fixed() +
      coord_flip() +
      annotate('text', x = 98, y = -800000, 
               label = 'Laser PROFILE', size = 3) +
      geom_bar(data = subset(dflaser10sec1, pos == "9"), stat = "identity") +
      geom_bar(data = subset(dflaser10sec1, pos == "10"),  stat = "identity") +
      theme_economist(base_size = 14) + 
      scale_fill_manual(values = c('#ff9896', '#d62728')) + 
      ggtitle(paste0('profile of the laser setup, ', title)) + 
      ylab('Value') + 
      xlab('Laser Position') + 
      theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank()) + 
      guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))

    print(g1)

  }

}, movie.name = 'laser.gif', interval = 0.1, ani.width = 700, ani.height = 600)
```

Comment: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1436): x, y, fill, width
In addition: Warning messages:
1: `panel.margin` is deprecated. Please use `panel.spacing` property instead 
2: `legend.margin` must be specified using `margin()`. For the old behavior use legend.spacing